# Trimming the video using UIVideoEditorController

Tags: iphone, video, trim, uivideoeditorcontroller

Can anyone please tell how to trim the video using UIVideoEditorController?

Comment: Check this example:
http://iphone-book-sample.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Chapter12/UIVideoEditorControllerSample/