# UIImagePickerController allowsEditing = YES, getting untrimmed video after trimming

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, video, uiimagepickercontroller

**Problem:**

When I record a video in my `UIImagePickerController` with allowsEditing set to YES, and afterwards trim the video by using the trim-interface that comes after video capture, I get returned the original video, instead of the trimmed one.

**Setup:**

I am using a `UIImagePickerController` for video capture, with the `allowsEditing` property set to YES. In the delegate method `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`, I use `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL`from the info `NSDictionary` to get the path URL. [The official Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate) don't mention any Edited video URL unfortunately.

**Code:**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0)
        == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

        self.tempVideoPath = [[info objectForKey:
                                UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
    }
}
```

I realise this question is similar to [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673269/uiimagepickercontroller-with-camera-source-with-allows-editing-yes-video-trimm) [ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133110/video-trimming-in-uiimagepicker) posted here on SO, but there was no definitive answer why it doesn't work or why the option is even there. If it is intended like this, I don't understand why there is an 'allowsEditing' property for the picker.

EDIT: In the info dictionary I got back are the following keys:

```
info: {
    UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.movie";
    UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL = "file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/F12E4608-FE5A-4EE3-B4E2-8F7D2508C4C8/tmp/capture-T0x21d810.tmp.wabFCC/capturedvideo.MOV";
    "_UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingEnd" = "5.498333333333333";
    "_UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingStart" = "4.273402690887451";
}
```

Does this mean we have to trim it ourselves with this data? Then the Apple documentation isn't very clear about this. If so, do you know a good practice for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

take a look at the highlighted answer on this post:

[How to trim the video using AVFoundation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7141620/1557663)

I think it's exactly what you want. The answer uses UIImagePickerController too

Hope it helps,
**Mário**

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick and dirty Swift 5 example of how to trim the video from `UIImagePickerController`

```
extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        let mediaType = info[.mediaType] as! String

        dismiss(animated: true) { [weak self] in
            // Handle a movie capture
            if mediaType == kUTTypeMovie as String {
                guard let videoURL = info[.mediaURL] as? URL else {
                    SwiftyBeaver.error("Could not get URL for movie")
                    return
                }

                let editingEnd = UIImagePickerController.InfoKey(rawValue: "_UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingEnd")
                let editingStart = UIImagePickerController.InfoKey(rawValue: "_UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingStart")

                let startMilliseconds: Double?
                let endMilliseconds: Double?

                if let start = info[editingStart] as? Double, let end = info[editingEnd] as? Double {
                    startMilliseconds = start
                    endMilliseconds = end
                } else {
                    startMilliseconds = nil
                    endMilliseconds = nil
                }

                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Creating", message: "File is being processed", preferredStyle: .alert)
                self?.present(alert, animated: true)
                self?.process(srcVideoURL: videoURL, startSeconds: startMilliseconds, endSeconds: endMilliseconds) { (error) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if let error = error {
                            alert.title = "Whoops"
                            alert.message = "\(error)"
                            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                                self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                            }))
                            return
                        }
                        self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

enum VideoError: Error {
    case error(message: String)
}

extension ViewController {
    func process(srcVideoURL: URL, startSeconds: Double?, endSeconds: Double?, completed: @escaping (_ error: Error?) -> ()) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            let dstVideoURL: URL // some URL for the destination
            do {
                try self.handleNewVideo(srcVideoURL: srcVideoURL, dstVideoURL: dstVideoURL, startSeconds: startSeconds, endSeconds: endSeconds)
                completed(nil)
            } catch {
                completed(error)
            }
        }
    }

    func handleNewVideo(srcVideoURL: URL, dstVideoURL: URL, startSeconds: Double?, endSeconds: Double?) throws {
        guard let start = startSeconds, let end = endSeconds else {
            print("No video editing information. Copying file.")
            try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: srcVideoURL, to: dstVideoURL)
            return
        }

        print("Video editing information. Processing start \(start) end \(end).")
        let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(url: srcVideoURL)
        let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: videoAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
        exportSession.outputURL = dstVideoURL
        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov
        let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: CMTime(seconds: start, preferredTimescale: 1000), duration: CMTime(seconds: end - start, preferredTimescale: 1000))
        exportSession.timeRange = timeRange

        var error: Error? = nil
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        exportSession.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
            switch exportSession.status {
            case .completed:
                break
            case .failed:
                error = exportSession.error ?? VideoError.error(message: "Unknown failed error")
            case .cancelled:
                error = exportSession.error ?? VideoError.error(message: "Video Cancelled")
            case .exporting:
                error = exportSession.error ?? VideoError.error(message: "Video still exporting")
            case .unknown:
                error = exportSession.error ?? VideoError.error(message: "Unknown unknown error")
            case .waiting:
                error = exportSession.error ?? VideoError.error(message: "Waiting error")
            @unknown default:
                error = exportSession.error ?? VideoError.error(message: "Future error")
            }
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        })
        dispatchGroup.wait()

        if let error = error {
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any ways startMilliseconds & endMilliseconds giving always nil values.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a [`UIVideoEditorController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIVideoEditorController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIVideoEditorController) for this. It's [Delegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIVideoEditorControllerDelegate_ProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009028) specifies a method `videoEditorController:didSaveEditedVideoToPath:` which seems to be what you want.
There is sample code available [here](http://iphone-book-sample.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Chapter12/UIVideoEditorControllerSample/), as referenced in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130996/trimming-the-video-using-uivideoeditorcontroller).

Comment: How would this work in combination with the `UIImagePickerController` then? Why would the option for `allowsEditing` be there in the first place if you should use an other class?